# Android Hello World Error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import, adk

I'm having difficulty with the Hello World program on Android.  When I load up the blank application, I get the following:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Android.R is not imported yet so I import it, and then I get an error on "activity_main" and "R.menu"...  they apparently don't exist.  I tried commenting out the second one and the first one had a suggestion to switch it to switch it to setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item);

I only need to make an android program that accepts text input and displays results...  that's ALL I need to do...  Can someone help me getting this hello world wroking right?

Comment: Think @Java Overlord has lost his R.java file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Android.R is not imported yet so I import it

Remove import `android.R` and use yourpackagename.R

Comment: remove imports...And don't type anything manually.. just hover over `R.layout.activity_main` it will show the suggestion. then import other than android.R. Also check is R.java file exits in your `gen` folder. if it doens't exist clean project.

Comment: Android.R is the suggestion

And nothing is in the gen folder

Comment: it seems there are errors in your xml file...R.java won't create when there are errors in your xml file. Make sure that your xml has no erros and go `projecs-->clean`

Comment: There are no errors in the manifest file, and that's the only XML file I can find.

Comment: @JavaOverlord : probably you have problem in layout xml that's why R is not generated. simply comment `android.R`,`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` and `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);` then clean your project from `projecs-->clean` then you will get all error in console. fixed and then uncomment all lines from java code